# ObjectMaterialize in EF not firing on first level query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have a query such as:

```
Query Syntax 1 - Does not fire the somehandler;
var results = (from I in db.mytable
              select new myObject() {
                        column1 = i.Prop1
              }).ToList();

Query Syntax 2 - Does fires the somehandler event;
var results = (from I in db.mytable
               select I).toList();
```

in my ContextClass I have something like this:

```
((IOjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized +=  somehandler;
```

The only difference I see is that the first query builds a new object from the select results.

Any idea why the event wouldn't fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The event fires only for Entity object projections, that is why you see this behaviour.

> "If the query used a projection and there is no matching entity, the results are materialized into DbDataRecords (or anonymous types when a LINQ to Entities query was used) **instead of entity objects**,"  Ref -Programming Entity Framework (Julia Lerman)P-244)

The definition for ObjectMarialized states

> Occurs when a new **entity object is created** from data in the data source as part of a query or load operation.

Ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx

Since the projection does not create an Entity object, it does not fire the event.

Comment: Ok. Now that we have this established, how can we run an "ObjectMaterialized" kind of event on any poco object that comes out of an EF query? Btw, the event name is misleading. It should be named "EntityObjectMaterialized". That would be more specific to what it actually does.